# Buying Evil Genius pre-patched

Tags: evil-genius

I'm hoping to buy Evil Genius, but I remember there being two patches (official and unoffical), each which only worked with some versions. Does anyone know where I can get a copy that's pre-patched or works with whichever patch is better?

Comment: Sadly, the Steam version is version 1.0, not the 1.1 official or 1.2 unofficial patch.

Comment: @Powerlord Can the Steam version be patched?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[GOG.com's release](http://www.gog.com/en/gamecard/evil_genius) comes pre-patched to 1.01.  I successfully applied the [unofficial patch](http://wiki.n1nj4.com/index.php?title=Unofficial_Patch) to it without issue and completed the game with it.

[There has been some confusion](http://www.gog.com/en/forum/evil_genius/confused_with_patching_status) regarding the GOG.com version actually being 1.01.  However, [GOG.com contacted Rebellion](http://www.gog.com/en/forum/evil_genius/confused_with_patching_status/post4) who confirmed that it is indeed 1.01.  There are more details on this in the linked thread.

Comment: This is a really old question, but Rebellion outright lied about the Steam version being 1.01, so I doubt that the GOG version is either.  (Oh hey, I said something like this from my old user2974 account too...)

Answer (score 1):

The Steam version has a patch available [through their forums](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1638920).

*This patch contains the following things:

- All the files you would need from both the official US and EU Patch, carefully hand-picked and tested for use in the Steam version (also see: Readme.txt).
- Contents of the freely available Bonus CD, which is not included in the Steam version.
- Unofficial Patch 1.2, which was originally made for the non-Steam version (also see: Unofficial Patch 1.2.txt).*